# New SharePoint 2013 SP1 install Security Token Service Not Available in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sharepoint-server, security-token-service, windows-server-2012-r2

Just installed SharePoint 2013 SP1 on a brand new server and I am getting a 'Site has not been shared with you error' on Manage Secure Store Service. I then looked at the Health report and it looks like The Security Token Service is not available.

I tried just about everything that Microsoft says to do. I have restarted the service, reset the credentials ID, checked the service in IIS and browsed to the service, it is up and running. Everything in SQL has permissions and the account I am using has domain admin privileges.

Any suggestions?

Comment: under which account you login? can you create web application or other service apps? also can you browse the STS service from IIS?

Comment: I can browse to the STS service from IIS and get the page that the service has been created successfully. With options to test the service...I can create other service applications as well. But SSRS which requires the STS to work, I cant configure that service app.

Comment: I am using an account that has local and domain administration access rights

Comment: are you accessing the site from server? did you see any other error in Eventlog or ULS logs which may give us the idea?

Comment: I am receiving Event Log ID :8306 An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error...

Comment: could you please check if "Claims to Windows Token Service" service is started on one of the server in your farm. U can check from Manage service in Farm and also from services console at server.

Comment: Claims to Windows TOken Service is Running and has an automatic Startup Type. It uses the Local System as Log On User

Comment: could you please check from central admin? if it is running from Central admin, stop it and restart it.

Comment: It is Started in Central Admin. I have stopped and restarted the service. Still get same event ID

Comment: how many servers in the farm? this service is running on all servers? stop it, reboot the server and then start it.

Comment: This is currently a 1 server farm. We are using it as a testing environment until we are ready.

Comment: I have restarted all the services, and restarted the server. Still getting the same issue and same EventID 8306 in error logs

Comment: Full event error log:

Comment: Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          3/9/2015 11:34:22 AM
Event ID:      8306
Task Category: Claims Authentication
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SVC\_MeasureITSP
Computer:

Comment: Description:
An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs..

Comment: try to run thei pwoershell to reprovision the STS...$hostconfig = Get-SPServiceHostconfig
 
$hostconfig.Provision()
 
$services = Get-SPServiceApplication
 
foreach ($service in $services) { 

$service.provision();
write-host $service.name

}

Comment: I provisioned the STS application using the SharePoint 2013 powershell successfully and still having the issue with same error id.

Comment: their will be something else blocking this. do you  have antivirus on server? i am thinking may be you missing some .Net hot fix

Comment: Yeah it seems that there is something more advanced that the quick fixes that are out there in the SharePoint blogs. We have scheduled a premier support call with Microsoft tomorrow. Hopefully they can point us in the right direction. I will update this tomorrow with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally fixed the Security Token Issue. 
First thing is we needed to install the correct version of SharePoint 2013 SP1 slipstream version which can be downloaded on Microsoft's VLSC. After the installation we were still receiving the same issue and it turned out to be a GPO security setting. The FIPS policy setting was disabled so we needed to enable it.
A walkthrough to change the security setting is very nicely documented at Baris's SharePoint Blog: http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2013/09/sharepoint-installation-claims-error.html